# Discord.js v13 - Reactions

Tags: javascript

How to add a reaction to this without using message.react(), I have no idea how to do this

```
const discord = require('discord.js')
 
 
module.exports = {
    name: "vt",
    description: "---",
 
    run(Interaction, args, Client) {
        const text = Interaction.options.getString("text")
 
        const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(text);
        Interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
 
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just do like that

```
message.react('')
```

Or if you want to use custom emoji

```
message.react('<a:4fun:928230352600838144>')
```